# Should I use getApplicationContext() or getContext() in Intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

On button click I'm starting a new activity like this:

```
        Intent(requireContext(), SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(RECORDED_SUCCESSFULLY, filePath)
        (activity as FirstActivity).finish()
        startActivity(this)
        }
```

But because I need to finish this activity before creating a new one, requireContext() here will be occasionally equal null and this causes a crash. So my question is, can I use getApplicationContext() or should I use safe call with getContext() in this situation?

Comment: you can use activity context and start the activity. below you can call finish() method to kill the current activity

Comment: Is this in an on click listener? You can use `view.context`. `activity` is null only when the fragment isn't attached. So it should never be null whenever you're processing this, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's prefered to use Activityname.this or getApplicationContext().
Remember there are two types of contexts in android and when you are dealing with activity components such as finish use Activityname.this